# How to break json response data into multiple strings?

Tags: ios, json, string

I want to get JSON response in separate string form, here is my code

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"register=yes&email=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@&password=%@&birthDate=%@&zip=%@",txt_email.text,txt_firstname.text,txt_lastname.text,txt_pass.text,txt_dob.text,txt_adress.text];

// Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"URL"]];
  // set Request Type
  [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
//Log Response
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

And this is how i am getting in response.

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-13 14:39:54.597 Traquer[5594:207956] {
            "message": { "email": "email is required " , "fname": "fname is required " , "lname": "lname is required " , "password": "password is required " , "birthDate": "birthDate is required " , "zip": "zip is required "  },
            "boolean": false,
            "eType": 0
    }
```

I want my message, boolean, etype and other data in seperate strings.

Comment: You can use NSDictionary to store response data and by using key you can separate all of 3.

Comment: @NasirKhan NSArray *message=[returnData valueForKey:@"message"];
    NSString *boolean=[returnData valueForKey:@"boolean"];
    NSString  *eType=[returnData valueForKey:@"eType"];     Try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it..

**Code:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSArray *message=[dict objectForKey:@"message"];
BOOL boolean=[[dict  objectForKey:@"boolean"]boolValue];
NSString  *eType=[dict  objectForKey:@"eType"];
```

**Note:** `returnData` is the responce data coming form webservice.

Comment: The boolean object is NOT an NSString type ... probably it's an NSNumber with a boolean value. See @Halpo answer to know how to obtain the value the correct way.

Comment: @FormigaNinja Sorry for that but its my mistake it will happen because of i was in hurry. But thanks for giving suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AshokLondhe i didn't vote down for your answer brow.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna it's ok.. Down voting is down by FormigaNinja

Comment: As you fix your answer, I did undo my downvote too ... its pretty fair

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:nil];

 NSDictionary *message = responseDict[@"message"];

 NSString *email = message[@"email"];


 BOOL aBoolean = [responseDict[@"boolean"] boolValue];

 int eType = [responseDict[@"eType"] intValue];
```